# For what $c>0$ is $F$ a distribution function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let the function $F$  be defined by $F(t)=\begin{cases} 0 \ , \,t<0 \\ \frac{t^2}{c} \,, \, 0 \leq t\leq 5 \\-1+\frac{2t}{5}-\frac{t^2}{50}\,,\, 5 \leq t \leq 10 \\1 \, , \, t>10\end{cases}$

I had to figure out for which $c>0$ the function $F$ is a distribution function. So I checked rightsided continuity which resultet in $c=50$. Is that correct?

Comment: You are correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea here is that we need to find the density function $f(t)$ and then determine what constant $c$ enables the pdf to integrate to 1.

Let $F(t)$ be defined by

$$F(t)=
\begin{array}{cc}
 \left\{ 
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & t<0 \\
 \frac{t^2}{c} & 0\leq t\leq 5 \\
 -\frac{t^2}{50}+\frac{2 t}{5}-1 & 5\leq t\leq 10 \\
 1 & t>10 \\
\end{array}
 \\
\right.
\end{array}
$$

Taking the derivative, we get

$$F'(t) = f(t) =
\begin{array}{cc}
 \left\{  
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{2 t}{c} & 0<t<5 \\
 \frac{1}{50} (20-2 t) & 5\leq t\leq 10 \\
\end{array}
 \\
\right.
\end{array}$$

Then

$$\int_0^{5} \frac{2t}{c}dt + \int_5^{10} \frac{1}{50}(20-2t)dt=\frac{25}{c}+\frac{1}{2}$$

Since $f(t)$ has to integrate to 1 to be a proper density, we can solve for $c$

$$\frac{25}{c}+\frac{1}{2} = 1 \longrightarrow c = 50$$

Comment: Ok thanks but what if I just check for which $c$ the we have $\frac{25}{c}=F(5)$?

Comment: You can't do that because $F(5)=P(X \leq 5)$, which you won't know until you solve for $c$ using the pdf

Comment: Ok thanks for the help!

Comment: When you know $F$ is continous, then you can determine the value of $c$ with $F(5)$.

Comment: Hmmm... Computing the PDF is quite unnecessary, actually. It suffices to check that $F$ is nondecreasing on each interval (true for every $c>0$) and then that the two expressions of $F(5)$ coincide, that is, $$\frac{t^2}c=-1+\frac{2t}{5}-\frac{t^2}{50}$$ when $t=5$.

Comment: Yes I see...you are correct...thanks